# Running JS after theme customizer finished initialization

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I have a piece of JS code that I use show/hide customizer control groups depending on a select item value.

The code was working fine until recent wp update (not sure which version first broke this).

Here is the code for enqueuing the js file.

```
add_action('customize_controls_print_scripts', 'ppl_customize_controls_scripts');
function ppl_customize_controls_scripts(){
    wp_register_script( 'ppl-customize-control', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/customizer-control.js', array('jquery'), 1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ppl-customize-control' );
}
```

**The JS file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var skin_select = $('#customize-control-ppl-ninja-theme-options-skin').find('select');

    //alert(skin_select.attr('class'));
    var selected_val = skin_select.children('option:selected').val();
    var custom_group = [
        '#accordion-section-custom_header_styles',
        '#accordion-section-custom_slider_styles',
        '#accordion-section-custom_footer_styles',
        '#accordion-section-custom_general_colors'
    ];

    if(selected_val != 4){
        hide_custom_controls(custom_group);
    }

    skin_select.change(function(){
       var val = $(this).val();

        if(val != 4){
            hide_custom_controls(custom_group);
        }else{
            show_custom_controls(custom_group);
        }

    });

    function hide_custom_controls(custom_group){
        var selector = custom_group.join(',');
        $(selector).hide();
    }

    function show_custom_controls(custom_group){
        var selector = custom_group.join(',');
        $(selector).show();
    }

});
```

**The problem is**, JS loads and hides the customizer control section just fine with inline css `display:none`. Then the cusomizer js script revises it and update the inline css to `display:list-item` which makes them visible. So, I need to run the JS code later after the customizer loads fully.

I looked into customizer script in wp-includes directory but haven't find anything that I can use. Perhaps I missed something.

### Further Information

1. The code that revising the css can be found in [`/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js#L2584).
2. The script is using the `ready` event to add class and revise visibility of panels, sections and controls. But I am unable to add listener to that event.
3. The property activePanels, activeSections, activeControls are set from PHP from the file [`/wp-admin/customize.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/customize.php#L313) I have found no way to overwrite that variable as you can see it is printed just before the body tag ends.

So, the possible solution is perhaps finding a way to hook into the `ready` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, far the problem was with the initial loading of the JS file. As i couldn't find any solution using the JS. The problem was not about the script loading rather then the execution timing.

Anyways, The theme customizer looks into the global variable for which Panel/Section/Control it will show as active when it loads.

### How to Make Sections/Controls/Panels Active/Deactive on initial loading

After spending hours into the core files I have found solution.

1. For Panels use `customize_panel_active` filter. Passes two parameter `$active` boolean and `$panel` object.
2. For Sections use `customize_section_active` filter. Passes two parameter `$active` boolean and `$section` object.
3. For Controls use `customize_control_active` filter. Passes two parameter `$active` boolean and `$control` object.

**Example:** If I assume I have a panel and its id is `my_panel`. And I want to hide it if certain theme option is not set.

```
add_filter('customize_panel_active', 'maybe_panel_active', 10, 2);

function maybe_panel_active($active, $panel){

    if($panel->id == 'my_panel' && !theme_option('certain_theme_option') ){
        $active = false;
    }

    return $active;
}
```

That's about it! Pretty straight forward :)

**Note:** The solution is purely php. If anyone able to make it work by listening to the customizers JS events. I would be very interested on it as the question was initially intended for a JS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a timing problem to me, maybe/probably I'm oversimplifying this, but what about making use of the `$debs` parameter `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` are offering to control load order, where one of those - in the order they are added at `script-loader.php` - `customize-base`, `customize-loader`, `customize-preview`, `customize-models`, `customize-views`, `customize-controls`, `customize-widgets` or `customize-preview-widgets` should be a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a dependency problem. You're only checking for jQuery, so your script could be getting preempted. You can ensure your script loads after all the other customizer scripts with `'customize-preview-widgets'`. Try this…

```
add_action('customize_preview_init', 'ppl_customize_controls_scripts');
function ppl_customize_controls_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
          'ppl-customize-control',
          get_template_directory_uri().'/js/customizer-control.js',
          array( 'jquery','customize-preview-widgets' ),
          '',
          true
    );
}
```

Comment: Can't use `customize_preview_init` as I need the script to run in the parent window. Not in the iframe. The customizer finishes loading with bit delay, adding dependencies doen't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to divine the mysteries of the customizer javascript initialization, which as you say is far from clear, you could use a [custom control](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#custom-controls-sections-and-panels) to inject your javascript, by overriding the `render_content()`, eg

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function ( $wp_customize ) {
    // Custom control.
    class PPL_Ninja_Skin_Select_Customize_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
        public $type = 'select';

        // Override to inject our javascript.
        public function render_content() {
            parent::render_content();
            ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var skin_select = $('#customize-control-ppl-ninja-theme-options-skin').find('select');
    var custom_group = [
        '#accordion-section-custom_header_styles',
        '#accordion-section-custom_slider_styles',
        '#accordion-section-custom_footer_styles',
        '#accordion-section-custom_general_colors'
    ];

    skin_select.change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 4) {
            $(custom_group.join(',')).hide();
        } else {
            $(custom_group.join(',')).show();
        }
    });
    skin_select.change();
}());
</script>
            <?php
        }
    }

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'ppl-ninja-theme-options-skin' );
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'ppl-ninja-theme-options', array(
        'title' => __( 'Ninja Options', 'ppl' ),
    ) );

    // Add custom control.
    $wp_customize->add_control( new PPL_Ninja_Skin_Select_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize, 'ppl-ninja-theme-options-skin', array(
            'label' => __( 'Skin', 'ppl' ),
            'section' => 'ppl-ninja-theme-options',
            'choices' => array(
                '' => __( 'Select', 'ppl' ),
                1 => __( 'One', 'ppl' ),
                2 => __( 'Two', 'ppl' ),
                3 => __( 'Three', 'ppl' ),
                4 => __( 'Four', 'ppl' ),
            ),
        )
    ) );

    // Test data.
    foreach ( array( 'header_styles', 'slider_styles', 'footer_styles', 'general_colors' ) as $setting ) {
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_' . $setting . '-setting' );
        $wp_customize->add_section( 'custom_' . $setting, array(
            'title' => sprintf( __( 'Ninja %s', 'ppl' ), $setting ),
        ) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'custom_' . $setting . '-setting', array (
            'label' => __( 'Setting', 'td' ),
            'section' => 'custom_' . $setting,
        ) );
    }
} );
```

(also don't bother with any CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Although not a pretty solution, maybe you can sample it using window.setInterval() and once visible stop the interval and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Yes, it was the backup solution ;)